# Time-series regression

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study, multiple-regression

Suppose that a typical firm determines its level of stocks $H_t$, in accordance with the following rule: $H_t - H_{t-1} = \lambda (H^*_t - H_{t-1}) + \epsilon _t$
where $\epsilon _t$ is a serially uncorrelated disturbance term with mean zero and constant variance $\sigma^2$.

$H^*_t$, the desired level of stocks, is given by the exact linear relationship
$H^*_t = \phi S_t$, where St is the current level of sales.

Derive an expression for $H_t$ in terms of current and past values of $S_t$, and discuss
briefly how you would estimate the parameters $\phi$ and $\lambda$ given time series data on stocks and sales.

- I have substituted $H^*_t$ but this only gives me an expression with current value of sales. I am not sure how to proceed with this and then estimate?

Comment: is this homework ? If so, please add self study tag.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: How is level of stocks is determined by level of sales, when sales are not known in advance?

Comment: The change in the level of stock depends on a function of the difference between desired and previous level of stock, where desired level of stock is based on current sales. That is what I think it means.

Answer (score 4):

$$H_t - H_{t-1} = \lambda (H^*_t - H_{t-1}) + \epsilon _t$$

$$\Rightarrow H_t  = \lambda H^*_t +(1-\lambda)H_{t-1} + \epsilon_t \tag{1}$$

Writing it also for $t-1$,

$$ H_{t-1}  = \lambda H^*_{t-1} +(1-\lambda)H_{t-2} + \epsilon_{t-1} \tag{2}$$

Insert $(2)$ into $(1)$

$$(1),(2) \Rightarrow H_t  = \lambda H^*_t +(1-\lambda)\big[\lambda H^*_{t-1} +(1-\lambda)H_{t-2} + \epsilon_{t-1}\big] + \epsilon_t $$

$$\Rightarrow  H_t  = \lambda H^*_t +(1-\lambda)\lambda H^*_{t-1} +(1-\lambda)^2H_{t-2} + (1-\lambda)\epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$

$$ = \lambda \phi S_t +(1-\lambda)\lambda \phi S_{t-1} +(1-\lambda)^2H_{t-2} + (1-\lambda)\epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t \tag{3}$$

and the lags of Sales have appeared. Write $(1)$ for $t-2$, insert into $(3)$ etc.

Comment: Thank you. So do you get Ht=λϕSt + ϵt + SUM[(1-λ)^n λϕSt-n + ϵt-n] when you insert infinitely? Or is that unnecessary?

Comment: It depends. You say that you will have data on both Sales and Stocks. So in principle there are two options here: either continue substituting "at infinity", to eliminate totally stocks from the right-hand side (and in practice truncate eventually the lag-length), or stop at a certain point and consider using as regressors both past Sales and past Stocks. These are models with different properties (the second has lags of the dependent variable in the regressors). There is no single decision here, it depends on various aspects of the actual case at hand.